# Why this code return undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, why this code return undefined?

```
    const foo = {  
      bar: function() { return this.baz; },
      baz: 1,
    };

    console.log((function() {
      return typeof arguments[0]();
    })(foo.bar));
```

Comment: Where did you find this code? That IIFE and `arguments[0]` thing looks unnecessarily complicated and irrelevant to your question.

Comment: When you are executing arguments[0]() `this` refers to the context it was called in, in this case, it would most likely be `window` and `window` won't have a property called `baz`

Comment: @Tushar Are there? Feel free to reopen and answer, but I think the only/main problem is the misunderstanding of the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: @JohanP Actually `this` will refer to the `arguments` of the IIFE, but yes it's just weird.

Answer (score -1):

If you are expecting an answer of `number` that can not be returned from you code.
This is a misunderstanding of this keyword (as pointed out by @Tushar @Bergi)

The following code does it.

```
function Foo(){
    this.baz = 1;
};

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    "use strict";
    return this.baz;
}

var foo = new Foo();
console.log((function() {
    "use strict";
    return typeof arguments[0];
})(foo.bar()));
```

Comment: The problem is with calling the `bar` function. Not just show the typeof that variable.

Comment: What do you think is the "correct result" and why? I'm pretty certain that the OP expected `"number"`, the typeof `1`, which is not what this code yields.

Comment: Edited the code for yeilding `number`.

Comment: Yes, you moved the call, but why did you change `foo` to be an instance with a prototype?!

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? (apart from creating an instance) @Bergi

Comment: How can you consume the use of `this` keyword without creating an instance?

Comment: The original object literal would have worked just fine. What do you mean by "*consume the use of `this`*"?

Comment: Can you please edit the answer or suggest a new answer to the one you are referring to?